# Dynamically selecting information from a MySQL database using a JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, jcombobox

It was a little difficult to explain the problem properly in the title, but this is what I am struggling with;

I am making a program that will hopefully predict the result between two football teams using their previous results. The results will be stored in a mysql database. There are 21 tables in the database, 1 is the results of all matches in the past 3 years, and the other 20 are for each team containing various information of that team.

My problem is connecting to the table which contains results of all matches using two jcombobox and retrieving information for matches between two specific teams.

For example, this is the code for the two jcombobox.

```
private String[] homeTeam = { "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Cardiff", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Fulham",
"Hull", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland",
"Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham"};                                                             
private JComboBox box1 = new JComboBox(homeTeam);

private String[] awayTeam = { "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Cardiff", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Fulham",
"Hull", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland",
"Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham" };                                                             
private JComboBox box2 = new JComboBox(awayTeam);
```

So, say I want to find the results if the home team was Cardiff, and the away team was Hull, I know what sql query I would need to write to do that. But my problem is there are so many different possible combinations of teams that I would end up needing to write hundreds of queries.

Is it possible to do this dynamically, rather than writing a query for every possible combination of match?

Thanks

Comment: Part of the issue is that you really shouldn't have a separate table per team; instead, you should have a `team` field in a single table that lists all the players.

Comment: Please rephrase your title. You don't want to dinamically connect to the database, you want to dinamically select data from a table

Comment: I need separate tables for each team because I'm using variables from this season also to predict the result, and the data for these is held in the table for each team. I didn't mention that in the original post because I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PreparedStatement. You have to write one Statement and the values can be set dynamically out of the JComboBoxes.